# FireDAC Refresh ou RefreshRecord

Tags: delphi, firedac

Estou passando por uma situação inusitada com FireDAC.

Utilizo o Delphi 2009 + FireDAC v8.0.5.3365 e apenas um componente `ADQuery` sem `DataSetProvider` e `ClientDataSet`.

Após a inclusão  de um registro através do `ApplyUpdates(0)`, quando solicito um *Refresh* ou *RefreshRecord* o FireDAC está gravando o registro mais duas vezes, causando uma triplicidade na inclusão. Isso já aconteceu umas três vezes em tabelas diferentes.

Já tentei desativar o `CachedUpdates`, mas apresenta erro se essa alteração for realizada com a *Query* aberta.

Alguém já passou por isso? Sabe como resolver essa situação?

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente com o comando: `CommitUpdates` após `ApplyUpdates(0)` consegui resolver dois problemas:

1. Evitar a triplicidade de registros na tabela.
2. Evitar erros no comando *Refresh* após a inclusão / alteração dos dados.

No fórum da empresa Da-Soft (link abaixo) tem uma chamada de suporte que a solução é realmente esta, chamar `CommitUpdates` logo após `ApplyUpdates(0)`.

[resposta oficial Da-Soft desenvolvedora do AnyDac/FireDac](http://www.da-soft.com/forums/anydac-general-english/cached-updates-autocommitupdates.html)

> 2) `FAutoCommitUpdates` é verdadeiro apenas para `TADMemTable`.  Isso é necessário para a compatibilidade com `TClientDataSet`.  Para todos os outros você tem que chamar explicitamente `CommitUpdates` após `ApplyUpdates`... dataset AnyDAC.

Answer (score 0):

Tente verificar se no evento `after refresh` ou `before refresh` ou outro evento não chama de volta o procedimento de inclusão desse registro.

Eu particularmente trabalho da seguinte forma:

No `fdquery` deixo um `select` e quando vou inserir um registro realizo um `append`, depois um `post` e ai sim um `refresh` para atualizar o grid, e nunca cheguei a ter esse problema.

Se chegar a trabalhar com o `begintrans` e `commit` aplique primeiro o `apply` ou o `post` e depois realize o `commit` se não o controle de transações nao irá adiantar muita coisa.